# Complex matrix division when only the amplitude of the vector to be divided is known.

Tags: matrices, divisibility

Let A be a known complex matrix, B a complex vector, and C the complex vector to be solved.
Imagine that we know that AC = B . Let assume that the number of lines of A and B are as many as needed. (In my problem, with an unchanged size for C, I can easily increase the number of lines of A and B ).
How can I find C when only Q = [|B1|, |B2|, |B3], |B4|, ...,|Bn|] is known ?

So far I tried to solve this problem by multiplying by the conjugate :
(AC)*conj(AC) = Q*Q, where * is element by element multiplication.
but at the end, i didn't find any solution.

Comment: So you are asking for all vectors $C$ that have $AC$ lie in the sphere of radius $|B|$. This will give some kind of ellipsoid as solution set. This is a very ill-posed problem if you want to find a specific vector. Can you flesh out the background a little bit more, so that perhaps a more specific solution can be found?

Comment: Thanks you a lot for your post. Thanks you for the attention you gave to me. I am afraid, I have to work more on my side to present you in a clean way what my problem realy is. Thanks you by the way because, before I read your post i was not aware of what was a Lie group.I think a nead one week (because it is only for me a hobby occupation and i have plenty other things to do before =) ). I have to look and see if it is a problem to have several solutions.

Comment: It is nice that it was inspiring to you, but that the matrix-vector product "lie"s on a sphere means here just that it is situated on that sphere, "lie" as "to lie down" or "to lie on the ground", not as in "to tell an untruth" and not as in "Sophus Lie".

Comment: I realized later my bad understanding of lie (my english is not perfect). By the way I have edited my post because I think it was baddly explained, especially the |B| notation was not the good one. It makes the problem more constrained. By the way I am French and working from Toulouse, were you have made some studies, not far from 'Université Paul sabatier' seen on your linkedin public page !

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment; to recapitulate: Given are a matrix $A\in \Bbb C^{m\times n}$ with complex components and a vector $Q\in\Bbb R^{m\times 1}$ of non-negative real numbers. Further, the number $m$ of rows of $A$ and $Q$ is at least twice the number $n$ of columns of $A$, $m\ge 2n$.

We now consider the torus 
$$
T=\{B\in \Bbb C^m: |B_k|=Q_k\}
$$
and ask for solutions $C$ of
$$
AC\in T.
$$

---

Geometrically, this means to compute the intersection of the hypertorus $T$ with real dimension $m$ (as long as all components of $Q$ are positive) and the subspace $Im(A)$ of real dimension $2n$. Since the real dimension of the full space is $2m$, and $2n+m\le 2m$, chances are high that the intersection is empty.

Put another way, if $a_k$ are the rows of $A$, then the vector $C$ with $2n$ real unknowns is bound by $m\ge 2n$ non-linear equations $|a_kC|^2=Q_k^2$, thus the non-linear system of equations is over-determined.

Comment: This is exactly the exact problem. Thanks for your help. I have once again edited my question. The reason for it is that I can easyly increase or decrease the 'm' dimension. The question is : what is the best choice for m ? Does it depend of A ? If the problem is over constrained can we choose a least sqare error approach to solve it ? Can you redirect me to some classical(?) appropriate algorithms for the resolution  ? Thank you very much indeed for all your help .

Comment: For the moment, I have written all the derivative of |a_kC|^2, with respect to the modulus and phase angle of all the C_k on one hand and of the Real and Imaginary part of C_k on the other hand. I am planning to use these derivative in a gradient based optimisation .

Comment: Yes, that is one way to do it. However, I would think it would be easier to write the equations in terms of the real and imaginary parts of the $C_k$. But still, the least square formulation will be of degree 4 and the system of derivatives of degree 3, so some Gauß-Newton or quasi-Gauß-Newton will be required.

Comment: There is no way to tell what $m$ should be. From the dimensions it should be $m=2n$ so that the solution set is zero-dimensional (for a generic perturbation of the system). But still, the number of real solutions or any solutions at all could be zero.